# Custom DNS for Cloudfront returns 403

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Cloudformation to deploy resources. This includes a Cloudfront CDN and a RecordSet. I want this to create a new record set for a custom domain `test.example.com`, that will point to my Cloudfront CDN, which points to an S3 bucket. After successful deployment, I get the following error:

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

Testing using the Cloudfront Domain is successful. When I check the AWS console, the only thing I notice is that the Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) is empty:
[image]

When I populate that with the expected value `test.example.com`, the page loads just fine.
I have tried adding `Aliases: test.example.com` to the Cloudfront `DistributionConfig` but then I get a circular error with the RecordSet.

How can I have both the CDN and the RecordSet in Cloudformation, with the Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) populated?

Cloudfront:

```
  Distribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          -
            # Use the Website as the origin
            DomainName: !GetAtt 'Website.DomainName'
            Id: !Ref Website
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Join [ '', [ 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/', !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity] ]
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        CustomErrorResponses:
          - ErrorCode: 404
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
          - ErrorCode: 403
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - DELETE
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
            - PATCH
            - POST
            - PUT
          DefaultTTL: 60
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: true
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          # The origin id defined above
          TargetOriginId: !Ref Website
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: "redirect-to-https" # we want to force https
        # The certificate to use when using https
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:<id>:certificate/<certId>
          MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```

DNS:

```
  DNS:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: <<id>>
      RecordSets:
        - Name: test.example.com
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
            DNSName: !GetAtt
              - Distribution
              - DomainName
```

Comment: You need `Aliases` in CF distro. So I would concentrate on "I get a circular error " issue. Can you clarify exactly what you tried and what is the error.

Comment: @Marcin when I add the following to the Cloudfront resource, I get the error: `Aliases: !Ref DNS`. Error: `Circular dependency between resources: [DNS, Distribution]`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is successful when I add the following to the Cloudfront distribution:

```
Aliases:
  - test.example.com
```

My mistake is I was previously referencing the DNS:

```
Aliases: !Ref DNS
```

which was incorrect and causing my circular dependency issue